# In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B ....?

Tags: matlab

When i run my program for 4 iterations there is no problem but if i run it for more than 4 i get the following error

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B
and
I must be the same.
```

for the following line

```
Corresponding_value_of_x1(i)=x1(f==Lowest_value_of_the_objective_function(i));
```

Please help.

```
maxit=5
iga=1

x1=(6.*bin2dec(String_1))./1023
x2=(6.*bin2dec(String_2))./1023


for i=1:1:maxit


f=(x1.^2+x2-11).^2+(x1+x2.^2-7).^2;



  %Displaying results from the iteration
         i;
         Lowest_value_of_the_objective_function(i)= min(f);                                                                         

        Corresponding_value_of_x1(i)=x1(f==Lowest_value_of_the_objective_function(i)); 


        nx1=(6.*bin2dec(New_string(1)))./1023;
        nx2=(6.*bin2dec(New_string(2)))./1023;

        x1=nx1;
        x2=nx2;


end


         Corresponding_value_of_x1
```

Comment: You need to post the code and data, or at least enough to reproduce the issue. Help us to help you!

Comment: but its a very huge code....ok i try

Comment: Not necessarily all of it, just the relevant bit

Comment: `f==Lowest_value_of_the_objective_function(i)` returns more that one value

Comment: @am304 i did..maybe this much will do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to find the minimum of a vector, then the corresponding location of that value.  `min` will do all that at once, avoiding the problem you're running into:

```
[Lowest_value_of_the_objective_function(i) Corresponding_value_of_x1(i)] = min(f);
```

Note that your error is occurring because the same minimum value is appearing more than once.  This code will return the first of those minimum values.  If you want different behavior, you'll have to code it.